# Update edited post

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hey I was wondering if anyone could help, i need to edit and update a post, i have got the edit part working but the update I've been stuck on for hours

Edit blade.php

```
  <h2 class="text-center">Edit</h2>
<form action="{{ route('posts.update',['post' => $post]) }}" method="Post">

 @method('PUT')
    
    @csrf
    <textarea input="" class="col-12 pb-5 mt-4"  name="edit">{{$post->content}} 
    </textarea>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary col-2 mt-4">Edit</button>
        </div>              
</form>

@endsection
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}/edit', [PostController::class, 'edit'])->middleware(['auth']);
Route::put('post/{post}','PostController@update')->middleware(['auth']);
```

postController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //get the current user
    $user = Auth::user();
    //attach the content to allow comment 
    $user->posts()->create([
        'content' => $request->input('content'),
        'allowComment' => true,
    ]);

    // return to posts page
    return redirect('/posts');
}
```

PostController

```
//edit returns a view 
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    return view('edit', ['post' => $post]); 
}
```

update

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
 {
     //get the current user
     $user = Auth::user();
     //attach the content to allow comment 
     $user->posts()->create([
         'content' => $request->input('content'),
         'allowComment' => true,
     ]);
     // return to posts page
 

     return redirect('/posts');
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... so whats the problem?

Comment: Hey so i have a post i can edit the post but i cant update the post, I'm a beginner and i think its just not finding the updated post

Comment: why can you not, what is the problem, what is actually happening, are you getting an error .......

Comment: so im getting this error rn The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

Comment: but i dont think that its linking to the updated function at all

Comment: why are you "creating" in "update" ? 

please dd your code ... dd($request->all(), $post) at the very first line of update method ... that would give you hints of what is your problem

Comment: yes because you are not using the URL for that route, the route you defined has a route parameter, it is not `/posts`

Comment: so would it be posts.update in the action and a PUT method?

Answer (score 0):

After all the comments ...

```
<form action="/posts" method="Post">
```

should be

```
<form action="/posts/{{ $post->id }}" method="Post">
```

Comment: Undefined variable: post_id (View: /Users/ash/Code/socialnetwork/resources/views/edit.blade.php)

Comment: you should use whatever comes from your model, it should be {{$post->getKey()}}

Comment: @ashley it just a typo on this answer.  I edited, try now

Comment: in my terminal this is the  Domain | Method    | URI                             | Name                | Action

 PUT|PATCH | posts/{post}                    | posts.update        | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@update

Comment: its bringing me back to the posts page but isn't updating

Comment: can I add images to this chat?

Comment: hmm ive added a $user = save();

Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\save()

Comment: @ashleygibson you are not doing any 'updating' anywhere, you are creating new post records and your input is not named `content`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.update',['post' => $post]) }}" method="Post">

 @method('PUT')
    
    @csrf
    <textarea input="" class="col-12 pb-5 mt-4"  name="edit">{{$post->content}} 
    </textarea>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary col-2 mt-4">Edit</button>
        </div>              
</form>
```

pass the whole object to route instead of passing id

Comment: heyo that came up a different error Action PostController@update not defined. (View: /Users/ash/Code/socialnetwork/resources/views/edit.blade.php)

Comment: isnt that what i did in web.php

Route::put('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'update'])->middleware(['auth']);

Comment: please define your route as Route::put('post/{post}','PostController@update')->middleware(['auth']);

Comment: Target class [PostController] does not exist.

Comment: please check your name of controller it seems like your controller is named as postController instead of PostController

Comment: it is PostController

Comment: In your terminal execute this command php artisan route:list and send me screen shot

Comment: my original route of post is Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class)->middleware(['auth']);

Comment: apologies how to i send a screenshot on here?

Comment: leave the screenshot I've edited my code above use that instead of action method use route method of laravel

Comment: <form action="{{ route('posts.update',['post' => $post]) }}" method="Post"> like this

Comment: hey ok its returning to the posts but not updating

Comment: i have updated my code up above to what i have now

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates visit this link for documentation of update method

Comment: //get the current user
        $user = Auth::user();
        //attach the content to allow comment 
        $user->posts()->find([
            'content' => $request->input('content'),


        ]);

        $user->save();

Comment: thank you so much for helping me btw, I'm only a beginner

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.

Comment: send me your code snippet so i can correct your code